# Core data id and Web JSON api id does not match?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift3

I am not able to match Core Data Bookmark ID and JSON Web API ID, and I am not able to save image From JSON API to Core Data.

**Mainclass**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import SDWebImage
import CoreData
class InfoViewController: UIViewController  , MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
 var get_details : schools?
 var bookmark : [Bookmark] = []

 var bookmark_details : Bookmark?


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

        func bookmarktoCoredata(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add BookMark", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default){
            (action) in

//            for bkms in self.bookmark
//            {
//                if ((bkms.name)) == ((self.get_details?.name)!){
//                   
//                    print("same name")
//
//                }else{
//                     print("not same")
//                }
//            }

            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


            let task = Bookmark(context: context)

            if (task.bookmark_id) == Int16((self.get_details?.schoolid)!){
                print("same id")
            }
            else
            {
                print("not same id")
                task.bookmark_id = Int16((self.get_details?.schoolid)!)

                task.name = self.get_details?.name
                task.address = self.get_details?.address
                task.district = self.get_details?.district
                task.country = self.get_details?.country
                task.phone = self.get_details?.phone
                task.email = self.get_details?.email
                task.website = self.get_details?.website
                task.institution = self.get_details?.institution_type
                task.establishment = self.get_details?.establishment_date
                task.admission_open = self.get_details?.admission_open_from
                task.admission_end = self.get_details?.admission_open_from
                task.latitude = (self.get_details?.latitude)!
                task.longitude = (self.get_details?.longitude)!
                task.bookmark_type = "school"

//              let img = UIImage(named: "App.png") //Sending direct image its working
                let img = UIImage(named: (self.get_details?.logo)!) //by Json it sendong nil
                let imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1)
                task.logo = imgdata! as NSData


            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            }

        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel){
            (alert) in
//            JLToast.makeText("Your Bookmark Cancel !!").show()
        }
        alert.addAction(add)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I can't figure out why my code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not fetching a Bookmark with id. Try this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import SDWebImage
import CoreData
class InfoViewController: UIViewController {
var get_details : schools?
var bookmark : [Bookmark] = []

var bookmark_details : Bookmark?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func bookmarktoCoredata(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add BookMark", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) {
        (action) in

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchId = Int16((self.get_details?.schoolid)!
        let bookmarkFetch: NSFetchRequest<Bookmark> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Bookmark")
        bookmarkFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookmark_id == %d", fetchId)
        do {
            let fetchedBookmarks = try context?.fetch(bookmarkFetch)
            // you should find 1
            if fetchedBookmarks?.count == 1 {
                print("same id")
            } else if fetchedBookmarks?.count == 0 {
                // There is no Bookmark with this id so create a new one
                let task = Bookmark(context: context)
                // Populate all the properties here and save
                task.bookmark_id = Int16((self.get_details?.schoolid)!)

                task.name = self.get_details?.name
                task.address = self.get_details?.address
                task.district = self.get_details?.district
                task.country = self.get_details?.country
                task.phone = self.get_details?.phone
                task.email = self.get_details?.email
                task.website = self.get_details?.website
                task.institution = self.get_details?.institution_type
                task.establishment = self.get_details?.establishment_date
                task.admission_open = self.get_details?.admission_open_from
                task.admission_end = self.get_details?.admission_open_from
                task.latitude = (self.get_details?.latitude)!
                task.longitude = (self.get_details?.longitude)!
                task.bookmark_type = "school"
                // I don't know the type of get_details?.logo
                if let imgdata = self.get_details?.logo as? NSData {
                    task.logo = UIImage(data: imgdata)
                }

                // Save your changes
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
            } else {
                // If you get here you have more than one with the same id. Fix error
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch bookmark: \(error)")
        }
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel){
        (alert) in
//        JLToast.makeText("Your Bookmark Cancel !!").show()
    }
    alert.addAction(add)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
extension InfoViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    //Put your MKMapViewDelegate functions here
}

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
extension InfoViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    //Put your CLLocationManagerDelegate functions here
}
```

Comment: i have try this one too but i am not getting match its saving all value duplicate

Comment: You might have saved data from before you tried the fix. Erase the app and reinstall. From now on, you will only be saving new Bookmarks when you have a new id.

Comment: i tried it but don't work again its saving duplicate id in core data bookmark entity

Comment: get_details?.schoolid is in Unit and bookmark_id is in Int16 so is there issue with these n image is not been save any solution sir thanks !!

Comment: done this all stuff but again saving duplicate value in core data don't know what is wrong and image is also being not saved in core data .

Comment: `UIImage(named:)` looks for an image with that name in your `Assets.xcassets folder`. If you don't have an image with that name you'll get `nil`. I don't understand what do you mean by Unit. You should have both Id of the same type. Try as `Int`

Comment: thanks it works i change data type in int16 of JSON api id in Int16 and it works great so much thank you sir ?? And can you help me in saving the image to core data

Comment: m getting error on image save "cannot convert value type String to expected argument type Data" and get_details?.logo type is string and task.logo type is Binary data !!!